# Is programmers.blogoverflow.com closed?

Tags: discussion, blog

The last blog was 8/11/2013 and http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/about/ links to a blog chat room that has been frozen.

I am interested in contributing to a programming blog, the first article would be about a visual studio extension that I have just finished.  I would be describing aspects of Visual Studio extensibility including Roslyn in the context of my extension.

Comment: I think most of us simply have no desire to invest time in the per-site blogs because they have such poor visibility on their corresponding SEs, especially compared to the official SE company blog. If you just want to contribute to "a programming blog" and not specifically to this site, it might be best to simply make your own blog using one of the many blogging services already out there.

Comment: One of the points that I would stress is that the blog is/was intended as a "these are things that the community is interested in." (at least, in my interpretation). I would urge you to participate more on the site to get a better feel of this community and its various interests.

Answer (score 7):

As the effective runner of the blog, I can, perhaps better than many, address this issue. The blog was always a challenge, you need people to write content that is interesting and relevant. You need editors to proof and correct entries. Getting quality participants with the time and motivation to do these things proved difficult over time.

Part of the blame lies with me, I was finishing university while working 30 hours a week and vice chairing and program chairing the local student chapters of IEEE and ACM respectively. Being elected moderator did not help things in terms of my workload.

Without Dynamic, this endeavor would have been impossible, if I was the brains, he was the heart. Unfortunately, he also ran into school commitments that proved intractable.

We could have been more organized in our approach and more aggressive in our recruitment of personnel but in the end, everyone was a volunteer and it was always an uphill battle to maintain momentum. A more topdown approach might have benefited us but I felt that allowing people to pick individual topics was fairer. I could have written far more content I did but I did not want the blog to be "World Engineer opines about stuff".

The platform, as Enderland alluded, is not terribly good. It's basically stock WordPress with all the issues inherent there. Visibility was never the best and I'm both amazed and grateful that we did well as we did. An article every two weeks for a year is no small thing when community sourced. My special thanks to Morons for providing so much content even as things fell apart and to MichaelT and others for expressing continued interest.

Lastly, I do not consider the blog dead, only deeply comatose. Same thing perhaps but some part of me refuses to admit true defeat.

Answer (score 6):

I think blogs in Stack Exchange are barely supported at best right now.

They are not letting sites create additional blogs, as we have had this discussion recently on a different site.

Don't forget if you want and write a good question you can self-answer, which in many cases can be a good way to showcase a "mini-blog." Not sure what you had in mind, though, as it sounds a bit "product sales-y."